# What logic should be used to label customers (monthly) based on the categories they bought more often in the preceding 4 calendar months?

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like this:

| user | type | quantity | order_id | purchase_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | travel | 10 | 1 | 2022-01-10 |
| john | travel | 15 | 2 | 2022-01-15 |
| john | books | 4 | 3 | 2022-01-16 |
| john | music | 20 | 4 | 2022-02-01 |
| john | travel | 90 | 5 | 2022-02-15 |
| john | clothing | 200 | 6 | 2022-03-11 |
| john | travel | 70 | 7 | 2022-04-13 |
| john | clothing | 70 | 8 | 2022-05-01 |
| john | travel | 200 | 9 | 2022-06-15 |
| john | tickets | 10 | 10 | 2022-07-01 |
| john | services | 20 | 11 | 2022-07-15 |
| john | services | 90 | 12 | 2022-07-22 |
| john | travel | 10 | 13 | 2022-07-29 |
| john | services | 25 | 14 | 2022-08-01 |
| john | clothing | 3 | 15 | 2022-08-15 |
| john | music | 5 | 16 | 2022-08-17 |
| john | music | 40 | 18 | 2022-10-01 |
| john | music | 30 | 19 | 2022-11-05 |
| john | services | 2 | 20 | 2022-11-19 |

where i have many different users, multiple types making purchases daily.

I want to end up with a table of this format

| user | label | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | travel | 2022-01-01 |
| john | travel | 2022-02-01 |
| john | clothing | 2022-03-01 |
| john | travel-clothing | 2022-04-01 |
| john | travel-clothing | 2022-05-01 |
| john | travel-clothing | 2022-06-01 |
| john | travel | 2022-07-01 |
| john | travel | 2022-08-01 |
| john | services | 2022-10-01 |
| john | music | 2022-11-01 |

where the label would record the most popular type (based on % of quantity sold) for each user in a timeframe of the last 4 months (including the current month). So for instance, for March 2022 john ordered 200/339 clothing (Jan to and including Mar) so his label is clothing. But for months where two types are almost even I'd want to use a double label like for April (185 travel 200 clothing out of 409). In terms of rules this is not set in stone yet but it's something like, if two types are around even (e.g. >40%) then use both types in the label column; if three types are around even (e.g. around 30% each) use three types as label; if one label is 40% but the rest is made up of many small % keep the first label; and of course where one is clearly a majority use that. One other tricky bit is that there might be missing months for a user.

I think regarding the rules I need to just compare the % of each type, but I don't know how to retrieve the type as label afterwards. In general, I don't have the SQL/BigQuery logic very clearly in my head. I have done somethings but nothing that comes close to the target table.

Broken down in steps, I think I need 3 things:

group by user, type, month and get the partial and total count (I have done this)

then retrieve the counts for the past 4 months (have done something but it's not exactly accurate yet)

compare the ratios and make the label column

I'm not very clear on the sql/bigquery logic here, so please advise me on the correct steps to achieve the above. I'm working on bigquery but sql logic will also help

Comment: music-services-tickets --> `tickets` in `2022-07-01`  belongs to a timeframe of `2022-11-01`  ?

Comment: no it doesn't you are right, I've made a mistake when typing the table. A month should include the present month + the previous 3 calendar months

Comment: thanks for confirmation. one more thing to clarify.  how label for May became `travel-clothing` ?  seems 270 clothing (60%) and 160 travel (36%) though I might be wrong.

Comment: I tried to make an example that showcases many combinations but made some mistakes/inconsistencies. In this case you are right that clothing is 270 out of 450 while travelling is 160.  Although I'm not set yet for what the exact rules would be so that could end up clothing or clothing-travel. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach. It looks a little bit messy and has a room to optimize but hope you get some idea or a direction to address your problem.

```sql
WITH aggregation AS (
  SELECT user, type, DATE_TRUNC(purchase_date, MONTH) AS month, month_no,
         SUM(quantity) AS net_qty,
         SUM(SUM(quantity)) OVER w1 AS rolling_qty
    FROM sample_table, UNNEST([EXTRACT(YEAR FROM purchase_date) * 12 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM purchase_date)]) month_no
   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
  WINDOW w1 AS (
    PARTITION BY user ORDER BY month_no RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  )
),
rolling AS (
  SELECT user, month, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(type, net_qty)) OVER w2 AS agg, rolling_qty
    FROM aggregation
 QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user, month) = 1 
  WINDOW w2 AS (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY month_no RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
)
SELECT user, month, ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(
         SELECT type FROM (
           SELECT type, SUM(net_qty) / SUM(SUM(net_qty)) OVER () AS pct,
             FROM r.agg GROUP BY 1
         ) QUALIFY IFNULL(FIRST_VALUE(pct) OVER (ORDER BY pct DESC) - pct, 0) < 0.10 -- set threshold to 0.1
       ), '-') AS label
  FROM rolling r
 ORDER BY month;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jaytiger, in the end I used another solution: after getting the monthly counts, I pivoted the types and did the 4-month running sum there and finally set some case  when rules for the %. However, your solution also does what I asked so I'll mark it as an answer